# Get Product Attribute value

Tags: magento2, php, shipping, shipping-methods

I have made a shipping Model in Magento 2 . Inside the collectRates function. I am getting all items in the cart and looping through them.

I can set the price based on the product title. But I can't get the value of the attribute this product has for example "shipping_code".

```
$products = $request->getAllItems();

foreach($products as $product){
   $productName = $product->getName();
}
```

I have tried everything.

```
$attributeValue = $product->getData('shipping_code');
$attributeValue = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('shipping_code');
$attributeValue = $product->getAttribute('shipping_code');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Magento/App/Code/module_folder/custom_shipping/Model/Carrier/custom_shipping.php

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request){

    $products = $request->getAllItems();
    foreach($products as $product)
    {
       $productName = $product->getName();
       $attributeValue = $product->getData('shipping_code');
    }



     $shippingPrice = "100";

    if ($productName == "test") {
        $shippingPrice = "200";
    }

    if ($attributeValue == "A") {
        $shippingPrice = "300";
    }

    $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
    $result->append($method);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: For `shipping_code` attribute make sure from Admin -> Stores -> Product Attributes -> Edit your attribute & Go to Storefront Properties & set `Used in Product Listing` to `Yes`

Comment: Thanks, this was off. Unfortunately,  this hasn't fixed the problem none of the ways above are getting the value.

Comment: Please paste your file code with path from magento root directory

Comment: Updated post with file and directory

Comment: Hi @Nathaniel Have u tried answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach($products as $product)
{
   $productName = $product->getName();

   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
   $shippingCode = $product->getData('shipping_code');
}
```

If somone gives answer without `objectManager` then it will be better.

Comment: Just gave this a go with no luck sorry :(

Comment: Ahh strage. Please make all to Yes on Admin for "Storefront Properties" & Check. Have u cleared cache?

Comment: `$shippingCode = $product->getData('shipping_code');`?

Comment: Didn't get to you

Comment: Just figured that out about the same time as you :)  Update your answer and will mark as correct you legend.

Comment: Updated. Great to hear solved :)

Comment: To low level but will do when i can.

Comment: $product->getId() doesn't seem to be working only works when i manually enter the id or the product for example 19

Comment: Please use `->getEntityId()`

Comment: Hmm no luck sorry :(

Comment: Try to get SKU & on basis of SKU use `->loadBySku($product->getSku())` or `->load($product->getSku())`

Comment: I can get the SKU the same way i get the title. But not when loading a product in the ObjectManager

Comment: $product->getProductId();  Working

Comment: Alos changed $product_item = $objectManager si is No to be confused with the previous product

Comment: How can we get it in admin panel product view page?

Comment: for me `$product->getAttributeText('shipping_code');` works great with his answer.

Answer (score 11):

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();

$myattribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('Your_Attribute_Code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

echo $myattribute;
```

if want to show  value of custom attribute in product page can use this code.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer uses the ObjectManager directly, which the author themself noted is an anti-pattern. The current best practice for this is to use DI to get the product resource model and use that rather than calling `getResource()` on the product model instance [which is deprecated since 2.2](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/AbstractModel.php#L884-L893).

> @deprecated 101.0.0 because resource models should be used directly

So an example implementation might look something like this:

```
class CustomShipping ...
{
    protected $productResource;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $productResource)
    {
        $this->productResource = $productResource;
    }

    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        ...
        $attributeValue = $this->productResource->getAttribute('shipping_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, another important thing to check is whether the attribute is being loaded for the `quote_item` context. Given that this seems to be a custom attribute, **most likely not**. So to make sure your attribute gets loaded in quote items, [you will need to define it on `catalog_attributes`](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/216791/20131) like this:

`Magento/App/Code/module_folder/custom_shipping/etc/catalog_attributes.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="shipping_code"/>
    </group>
</config>
```